# Reload page after delete item in IONIC4

Tags: angular, ionic4, reload

Good day expert in the house.
Please am currently building an e-commerce mobile app with ionic 4, am having difficulty updating my item-total summary when an item is deleted from the cart page.

**This my cart.html page below**

```
    <ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar color="success">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="products"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="cart" [routerLink]="['/cart']"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge color="primary">{{ cartItem }}</ion-badge>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Cart</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content>
  <!--DISPLAY OF NO ITEM -->
  <div *ngIf="cartData.length == 0" class="ion-padding" >
    <ion-row size="12" disabled="true" class="ion-padding">
      <ion-col class="ion-padding-vertical">
        <h5 class="ion-text-center ion-padding-vertical">There is no Item in your cart...!</h5>
        <ion-button expand="block" color="success" [routerLink]="['/products']" class="ion-text-capitalize" style="font-size: 18px;">Browse farms</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
  <!--DISPLAY OF NO ITEM --> 
  <ion-card>
    <ion-list *ngIf="cartData.length > 0" >
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label class="headerTitle">Items in cart</ion-label>
        <ion-button [routerLink]="['/products']" >
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only"   name="add-circle" class="add_icon" color="success"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-list-header>


      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of cartData; let j = index" >
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <img [src]="item.images[0].src">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label>
          <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
          <p>Amount: <span style="color: rgb(26, 185, 26); font-weight: 400; font-size: 17px;">₦{{ baseProducts[j].price * baseProducts[j].quantity | number:'1.0-0'}}</span></p>
          <p >Returns: ‎₦{{ item.meta_data[1].value * baseProducts[j].quantity | number:'1.0-0' }}</p>
          <!--<ion-item>
           <ion-icon name="remove" class="decrement" (ionChange)="changeCartItemQty(baseProducts[j])"></ion-icon><span>{{ quantityValue }}</span><ion-icon (click)="increment()" name="add" class="increment"></ion-icon>
          </ion-text>-->  
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Change Quantity</ion-label>
              <ion-select value="brown" 
              okText="Okay" 
              cancelText="Dismiss" 
              [(ngModel)]="baseProducts[j].quantity" 
              (ionChange)="changeCartItemQty(baseProducts[j])">
                <ion-select-option value="1">1</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="2">2</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="3">3</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="4">4</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="5">5</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="6">6</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="7">7</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="8">8</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="9">9</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="10">10</ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-label> 

        <ion-button color="danger" (click)="removeFromCart(j, item)">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-card>


</ion-content>


<ion-footer *ngIf="cartData.length > 0" [routerLink]="['/checkout']">
  <ion-list >
    <ion-item >
```

Sub total

₦{{ calculatePrice() | number:'1.0-0'}}
        
        
          **Total Payment**
          **₦{{ calculatePrice() | number:'1.0-0' }}**

```
  <ion-button expand="full" color="success"  class="ion-text-capitalize">Proceed to checkout <ion-icon slot="end" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
</section>

</ion-footer>
```

**my cart.ts file**

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartserviceService } from '../services/cartservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.page.scss'],
})
export class CartPage implements OnInit {

  /* use below 4 variables at beginning so that cart page html works properly */
  cartData:any = [];
  baseProducts:any = [];
  totalPrice: number = 0;
  show: boolean = true;
  cartItem: number = 0;
  quantityValue:number = 1;

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private cart: CartserviceService) {
    this.cart.keepCartItemsOnRefresh();

    // products added to carts  
    this.storage.forEach((data)=>{
      let storedProducts = {};
      this.cart.keepCartItemsOnRefresh();
      let parseFromStorage = JSON.parse(data);
      this.cartData.push(parseFromStorage);
      storedProducts['product_id'] = parseFromStorage.id;
      storedProducts['price'] = parseFromStorage.price;
      storedProducts['quantity'] = 1;
      this.baseProducts.push(storedProducts);
    }).then(()=>{
      console.log('parse-prudcts', this.baseProducts)
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cart.cartItems.subscribe((value) =>{
      this.cartItem = value;
    });
  }



    //update in products

    changeCartItemQty(currentItem){
      this.baseProducts.forEach((productToUpdate) => {
        if(productToUpdate.product_id == currentItem.product_id){
          productToUpdate.quantity = parseInt(currentItem.quantity);
        }
      });
      this.cart.quantityUpdatedProducts = this.baseProducts;
      console.log('Changed Quantity on cart',this.cart.quantityUpdatedProducts);
    }
  // Delete item from cart
  removeFromCart(index, item){
  this.cartData.splice(index,1);
  let pId = item.id;
  this.storage.remove(`product_${pId}`);
  this.cart.keepCartItemsOnRefresh();

  }



  // calulate farm price
  calculatePrice(){
    this.totalPrice = 0;
    let farmPrice = 0;
    this.baseProducts.forEach((product)=>{
    farmPrice = product.price * product.quantity;
    this.totalPrice += farmPrice;
   });
   return this.totalPrice   
  } 
}
```

**I want the item total to update to the current item total in the cart when I delete an item from the cart**

Comment: Hey, Can you include only the critical parts of the code, so that we can know what to look for?

Comment: I have now included everything that has to do with cart page

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page? Its not good thing. Is the thing you want to achieve is to refresh the data or clear the deleted row or whats your purpose of reload?

Comment: Can you share this in stackblitz? too much code here to understand...

Comment: I just want when I delete an item, the item amount added will remove from total summary without reload the entire page. This is the cart page screenshot link.
https://gabaantech.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/cart-screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reload the complete page you can go for "window.location.reload()" or if you just want the updated data you can recall the specific API after deleting.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, really appreciate, it works but it reloads the whole page, is it possible to update the item total summary when an item is deleted without reloading the whole page or maybe add a spninner while the page reload. Thank you.

Comment: for that you have to create a service and subcribe to all those places where you want changes. So, it will make changes as the value get change from any end and get reflected to every subscribed.